# Does Zend Lucene support MultiValued Fields?

Tags: zend-framework, lucene

I wanted to know if Zend Lucene supports multivalued fields. I tried passing a an array to a field and it doesnt give any errors during indexing. But its not returning any results when i search. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't:

> Fields are always stored and returned from the index in UTF-8 encoding. 
>   Any required conversion to UTF-8 happens automatically.

I would think UTF-8 Encoding an array would not work, unless there's some recursion happening there. You could join the array with a "," or something or serialize or json_encode the array. If you are using it as a search index that might not work though. You could also use the Binary field type if you need to store something more complex like an image or something.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you add space-separated Text fields, they are stored as multiple fields, this is confirmed in Luke.

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field :: Text($fieldName, implode(' ', $fieldValue)));
```

The only problem then is that the values are lower cased because they are tokenized.